# Is dark.exe (from WiX) a reliable way to extract information from an MSI?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, regsvr32

... and if yes, why can't I use `SelfRegCost="0"`?

So this might get a little philosophical ;)

The basic problem is: I have to register a ShellExtension DLL during a setup. When using plain old VS2008 deployment, I had a custom action which ran a regsvr32 on my dll. Then in my WiX setup I did the same, even with an unregister (/u) on uninstall. This works fine.

Until the other day I had a problem with some third-party DLLs loosing their registration after uninstalling a Visual Studio Setup. I found the installation had overwritten the default location of the DLLs. I discovered the possibility to change the `Register` Property from `vsdrfCOMSelfReg` to `vsdrfDoNotRegister`, and now my Setup did not overwrite the default location any more.

This made me thinking that I can use the same Property to register my ShellExtension DLL. So lets use dark on the VS Setup and see what the translation of the `vsdrfCOMSelfReg` is. And I found the only difference is the attribute `SelfRegCost="0"` in the `File` tag.

But according to this article ( [How do you register a Win32 COM DLL file in WiX 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364187/how-do-you-register-a-win32-com-dll-in-wix3)) using SelfRegCost is baaad, lots of things go wrong. Possibly.

Now my reasoning is: either

a) dark.exe is not a realiable way to extract information from an MSI or

b) the use of `SelfRegCost="0"` is not as bad as everybody pretends, since Visual Studio does it eversince?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is exposing functionality; that doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it. Self-registration is bad and should be avoided by explicitly authoring COM registration using WiX elements like Class and ProgId.

Answer (score 2):

Dark is meant to decompile back to source but it isn't intended to be round tripped back via the compiler.  It's meant to be a useful starting point to clean up the code and do any needed refactoring then build it back up.