# Registering DLL's in Wix using self-registration

Tags: wix

Two of my library depends on the third. But the latter library must be copied to the system32 directory, another two - to the ProgramFiles directory. PLease could anyone advise on how to deal with registration of the first two libraries. **I need to use self-registration.** I tried to specify the id of the main library as a companion file, but it did not help. What should I do?

Comment: see related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364187/how-do-you-register-a-win32-com-dll-in-wix3/364544#364544

Comment: Is your problem that they won't register in the order that you want or that they won't register at all?

Comment: Question is whether you need proper *registration* or whether you must insist on *self-registration*. Self-registration is pretty bad and one of my thoughts reading your question was: what are the tasks besides registering the COM stuff that the person is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI's SelfReg table doesn't support ordering the operation of registrations. You could use the QuietExec custom action to call regsvr32 /s in the right order but I wouldn't do it myself.

The optimal design is to not rely on self reg.  Have you thoroughly exhausted using MSI to handle the registration data for you as it was designed to do?

Comment: I agree: registration has be part of MSI package itself rather than relying on self-reg.