# Manual registration of Excel COM addin

Tags: dll, com, wix, registry, atl

I have an Excel addin created using ATL COM. Usually this addin is installed using self registration, but I want to move away from that. I created an installer that manually adds everything to the registry. So far everything seems to load since Excel sees the addin, but I always get an error when trying to load it on startup. Even the LoadBehavior changes from 3 to a 2. Right now I am adding the values using `RegistryKey` and `RegistryValue` nodes, but when I looked at [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/364544/403429) with a similar topic I just didn't grasp what Rob had mentioned as the .rgs script doesn't have any proxy clsid or interfaces so I am not sure what I need to place there. Is there any online tutorial that I can use to help further understand manual registration in WiX?

**EDIT**

So I assume that the Proxy information comes from the .idl file instead of the .rgs. If that is true I think that I filled out the correct information needed. However, Excel still says that there was an error loading the addin during runtime. Any other information would be greatly appreciated.

Example:

```
<File Id="AddinDll" Name="addin.dll" Source=".\addin.dll" KeyPath="yes" >
    <TypeLib Id="TYPELIB-ID-HERE" MinorVersion="0" MajorVersion="1" Language="0" Description="addin" HelpDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION" >
        <Class Id="GUID-HERE" Context="InprocServer32" ThreadingModel="apartment" Version="1.0" Programmable="yes" Description="Example" >
            <ProgId Id="Addin.Example.1" Description="Example" >
                 <ProgId Id="Addin.Example" Description="Example" />
            </ProgId>
        </Class>

        <Class Id="PROXY-STUB-CLSID-HERE" Context="InprocServer32" ThreadingModel="both" >
            <Interface Id="INTERFACEID-HERE" Name="IExample" />
        </Class>
    </TypeLib>
</File>
```

Comment: Try running Heat on the file, to make sure you are getting all the necessary registration information. See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm

Comment: I tried heat. It throws an error saying that it can't open the DLL. Due to it being an ATL COM object it's always needed to be self registered. I want to finally be able to get away from that.