# How to register COM object in user machines

Tags: c#, c, com, windows-installer

Actually I am trying to create a modified version of putty that automatically pulls password from Server using Rest.
We have a C# library that provides the password(.dll).
But the putty source code is in plain C.
So I searched for a way to connect Managed (C#) and Unmanaged code(C/C++).I ended up in COM (Component Object Model) as a solution.
The COM object stores the path of the .dll in the registry.So any language can use the dll to retrieve the password. 
But i stucked up with how to register the CLSID of .dll in the user machine's registry. 
I found that it can be possible with the installer. But I can't find anything regarding how to register it with a installer. 
So whether Any samples that register COM using installer or procedure for how to create installer to register COM .dll in user machine will be useful for me.

Comment: For a .NET COM objects you can use regasm: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/registering-assemblies-with-com or here is an example of code that does almost the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782404/registering-a-com-without-admin-rights

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regsvr32.exe utility. See [How to register a .dll file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/844592/how-to-register-a-dll-file) for more information. The MSI installer in VS provides a built-in action for that. If you are using Wix, see [How do you register a Win32 COM DLL file in WiX 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364187/how-do-you-register-a-win32-com-dll-file-in-wix-3).

For managed assemblies you can use the regasm utility. Read more about this utility in the [Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool) section of MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will check it out