# Wix Installer: Uninstall Issue with DLL

Tags: wix, wix3.7, dllregistration

I have a DLL (for a MS Word plugin) configured in my .wxs file:

```
  <Component Id="cmpPluginDLL" 
             Guid="0C498C34-B546-4536-9933-9E7A52B1A541"
             Directory="PluginFolder">
    <File Source="MyWordPlugin.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
```

The first time I ran the installer, everything worked as anticipated - I was able to successfully use my plugin in Word.

I uninstalled via "Add/Remove Programs" and it appeared that everything removed fine. However, on subsequent builds and installs I am now getting a message that the DLL is invalid and no longer works in Word. I also tried uninstalling and then manually registering the DLL using "regsvr32.exe MyWordPlugIn.dll" but it now also returns an error saying it's invalid, where I could register it this way before.

I'm guessing when I uninstalled via Add/Remove Programs that something didn't get cleaned up properly but I have no idea where to look to resolve it. At this point I would just be happy to get regsvr32.exe MyWordPlugIn.dll working again.

I should add that I am new to Wix, and new at Windows development.

Thanks!

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/364187/7571258

Comment: That's actually super helpful. Now I just need to figure out how to fix what I broke so I can do it the right way :)